# Ant - printing a collection - map

Tags: ant, dictionary, jmx

I have an ant script that is executing a jmx get task:

```
<jmx:get
                name="java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Copy" 
                attribute="LastGcInfo"
                resultproperty="CopyLastGcInfo"
                />
```

Now, the LastGcInfo attribute has a map Map called memoryUsageBeforeGC. In this map there is a pair with a key called "value". Althoug I am unable to elicit it and print it out. I have tried to accomplish it like that:

```
    <echo>${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.value.used}</echo>
    <echo>${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.0.used}</echo>
    <echo>${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.used}</echo>
```

That didn't work. Do you have any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What 3rd party JMX ANT task are you using?

Comment: Hi Mark, it's org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example worked for me:

```
<project name="Catalina Ant JMX" xmlns:jmx="antlib:org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx" default="jmx">

    <target name="jmx" description="Show JMX stats">
        <jmx:open host="localhost" port="9012" username="controlRole" password="tomcat"/>

        <jmx:get name="java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Copy" 
                 attribute="LastGcInfo"
                 resultproperty="CopyLastGcInfo"
                 echo="false"
                 />

        <echo>
        memoryUsageBeforeGc
        ===================
        Perm Gen.used=${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.Perm Gen.used}
        Tenured Gen.used=${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.Tenured Gen.used}
        Eden Space.used=${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.Eden Space.used}
        Code Cache.used=${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.Code Cache.used}
        Survivor Space.used=${CopyLastGcInfo.memoryUsageBeforeGc.Survivor Space.used}
        </echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Example output

```
jmx:
     [echo] 
     [echo]         memoryUsageBeforeGc
     [echo]         ===================
     [echo]         Perm Gen.used=9660888
     [echo]         Tenured Gen.used=8393792
     [echo]         Eden Space.used=4456448
     [echo]         Code Cache.used=2038016
     [echo]         Survivor Space.used=172784
     [echo]
```

**Note**

- The "echo" attribute of the "jmx:query" task can be used to see the ANT properties and values created by the task. Useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Note that the names of the generations used in those expressions are JVM-specific and *can* change between versions (even in minor updates!).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Agreed. That was why I mentioned using the "echo" attribute in order to see the actual properties created by the ANT task.